# If $A$ is $2\times2 $ matrix such that $\operatorname{tr} A =\det A=3$ then trace of $A^{-1}=$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is $2\times2 $ matrix such that $\operatorname{tr} A=\det A=3$ then trace of $A^{-1}$ is?

$(A) \quad 1   \qquad
 (B) \quad \dfrac{1}{3} \qquad
 (C) \quad \dfrac{1}{6} \qquad
 (D) \quad\dfrac{1}{2}$

I did it in this way:

$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = 3 $$
$$\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2=3$$
$$\frac{1}{\lambda_1}+\frac{1}{\lambda_2} \implies
\frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{\lambda_1\lambda_2} \implies
\frac{3}{3}=1$$

I am practicing these types of question and after $5$ minutes of digging I came up with this answer. I wanna know if there is any alternative approach to solve this problem.

Comment: IMO, the way you found is better than the alternatives presented so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following nice and easy formula:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c & a
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic Polynomial for $A^{-1}$ for any invertible $n \times n$ matrix is
$$P_{A^{-1}}(X)=\det(xI-A^{-1})=\det(A^{-1}) \det(xA-I)=x^n\det(A^{-1})\det(A-\frac{1}{x}I)\\=(-1)^nx^n \det(A^{-1}) P_{A}(\frac{1}{x})$$

Now use the fact that for a $2\times 2$ matrix the characteristic polynomial is 
$$P_B(x)=x^2-\operatorname{tr}(B)x+\det(B)$$

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\det(A-\lambda 1)=a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c$, where $a,b,c$ are real numbers. It is easy to see that $a=1$.  Being the polynomial second degree, the sum of its roots is $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=-b/a=3$ and  their product $\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2=c/a=3$. Then the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-3\lambda+3$. The roots can be computed by Bhaskara and are equal to $\frac{3\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The trace of $A^{-1}$ is the sum of inverse eigenvalues for $A$:
$$
\frac{2}{3+i\sqrt{3}}+\frac{2}{3-i\sqrt{3}}=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Every matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation so

$A$ satisfies

- $A^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)A+\det(A)I=0 $

  and   $A^{-1}$ satisfies
- $A^{-2}-\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})A^{-1}+\det(A^{-1})I=0$.

With multiplying both sides of the first equation by $A^{-2}$ and dividing by $\det(A)$ we can easily obtain form of the second one.

**Edit**
I.e.

$$A^{-2}A^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)A^{-2}A+\det(A)IA^{-2}=0$$

$$I -\operatorname{tr}(A)A^{-1}+\det(A)A^{-2}=0$$

After changing the order of summands and dividing by $\det(A)$

$$A^{-2}- \frac{1}{\det(A)}\operatorname{tr}(A)A^{-1}+\frac{1}{\det(A)}I=0.$$

Comparing the last equation with the second one $\bullet$ we finally obtain

$$\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})=\frac{\operatorname{tr}(A)}{\det(A)}$$

Comment: Can you show me calculations also using your method ?

Comment: @Damn1o1 ok ........

Comment: @Damn1o1 Now, everything is clear ? In fact the method leads exactly to your formula but there is no mentioning eigenvalues ( although they are somewhere hidden in the background) Novelty in it is that we are using only matrix equation (hence its potential for higher dimensions)..

Comment: When you write \text{tr} instead of \operatorname{tr} then you won't get proper spacing in things like $3\operatorname{tr} A$ or $3\operatorname{tr}(A)$ unless you add it manually.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you Michael, I will try to memorize the tip.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 3 \\
\lambda_1\lambda_2 = 3
\end{align}
So you get $\lambda_2 = \dfrac 3 {\lambda_1},$ so the first equation above becomes
$$
\lambda_1 + \frac 3 \lambda_1 = 3.
$$
Multiply both sides by $\lambda_1$ and you have an ordinary quadratic equation.

The answer posted by "N.S." also leads to the same quadratic equation.